# Using selenium in python to get a list of users

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a bunch of code on a page that looks like this:

```
<div class="user">

    <span class="versus"></span>
    <a href="/users/USERNAME" target="_blank"></a>

</div>
```

I want to get a list of all the USERNAMEs.

I tried using

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("users")
```

as well as doing it by

```
(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a > span")
```

but I'm still having issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

(Also, im new to Python - how could I loop through my results and for example print all the usernames it finds?)

Comment: Please be clear. `I'm still having issues` doesn't really describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry - basically, i'm getting a no element found error.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work fine:

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='user']/a")`

OR

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a")`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the above answer to get the usernames:

```
users = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a") 
for user in users: 
    username = user.get_attribute("href").replace("/users/", "")
    print(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about these?

**href exact equals:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a[href='/users/USERNAME']")
```

**href contains:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a[href*='users']")
```

**href starts with:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a[href^='/users/']")
```

**href ends with:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a[href$='/USERNAME']")
```

If the username is in some piece of html, you can use element.get_attribute('href')

If I undertand your question, **this should work**:

```
users = [ elem.get_attribute('href').strip('/users/') for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.user > a[href^='/users/']") ]
```